# Python readline not giving expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from sys import argv

script,inputfile=argv

def print_all(file):
  print(file.read())

def rewind(file):
  file.seek(0)

def print_line(line,file):
  print(line,file.readline())

currentFile=open(inputfile)

print("Let's print the first line: \n")

print_all(currentFile)

print("Rewind")
rewind(currentFile)

currentLine=1

print_line(currentLine,currentFile)

currentLine+=1

print_line(currentLine,currentFile)


currentLine+=1


print_line(currentLine,currentFile)
```

I have this code, this works but what I don't understand is when I rewrite the print statement in the print line function to  print(file.readline(line)) I get an unexpected output. I am using python 3.6

correct output

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
Rewind
This is line 1

This is line 2

This is line 3
```

incorrect output

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
Rewind
T
hi
s i
```

why does this happen?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with an example file that contains these three lines. Maybe your input file has line break characters that your text editor does not recognize? Try `print(repr(file.read()))`

Comment: This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3

Comment: Your output does not match your code - I would expect your later lines to start with a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the function definition of `file.readline()`,

```
readline(...)
    readline([size]) -> next line from the file, as a string.

    Retain newline.  A non-negative size argument limits the maximum
    number of bytes to return (an incomplete line may be returned then).
    Return an empty string at EOF.
```

Hence, when you pass line number as an argument, you are actullay telling the number of  bytes which gets incremented with each `currentLine+=1`.

If you just intend to print the contents line by line, you can refer this,

```
def print_file_line_by_line(currentFile):
    for line in currentFile:
        print line.strip('\n')
```

or this also works

```
def print_file_line(currentLine, currentFile):
    try:
        print currentFile.read().split('\n')[currentLine-1]
    except IndexError as e:
        print str(currentLine)+' is greater than number of lines in file'
        print ''+str(e)
```

Comment: But OP never passes a line number. OP only counts a line number which they print *along* with the next line from the file. The `currentLine` is never used to interact with the file.

Comment: @poke: I think OP is lying about their code. This is the only sensible explanation for the output they are getting, so gets an upvote from me for being perceptive

Comment: @Eric As I explained in a comment to the question, it’s possible that the input file has characters that are invisible to OP’s text editor that count as line breaks to `readline`. And even if OP is lying about their code, the code they showed in the question is *perfectly fine* and works completely as expected, so this answer is not helpful.

Comment: @HarshitGarg Since passing `currentLine` to the `readline` call is indeed a likely cause of OP’s problem but OP’s code does not actually do that, I would suggest you to rewrite your answer to make it clear that you *believe* that OP is passing the current line despite the shown code—which should be working fine as it is.